# Do While Loop doesn't want to work for app

Tags: java, arrays, methods, do-while

Assignment is a 6 object array for a salon that needs to have the menu loop so the user can use all the sorts till they choose '0' to exit the app.Errors are posted below code.
I know I tried another way without using the 3 methods and got that to work  but I need to be able to use the methods and the do while anyone have any advice or input so I can make this work . Thanks

```
import java.util.*;

public class SalonReport
{
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
      int x =0;
  Service s1 = new Service();
  Service s2 = new Service();
  Service s3 = new Service();
  Service s4 = new Service();
  Service s5 = new Service();
  Service s6 = new Service();


  s1.setService("Cut");
  s1.setPrice(5.00);
  s1.setTime(15);

  s2.setService("Shampoo");
  s2.setPrice(5.00);
  s2.setTime(10);

  s3.setService("Manicure");
  s3.setPrice(20.00);
  s3.setTime(30);

  s4.setService("Style");
  s4.setPrice(60.00);
  s4.setTime(55);

  s5.setService("Permanent");
  s5.setPrice(28.00);
  s5.setTime(35);

  s6.setService("Trim");
  s6.setPrice(8.00);
  s6.setTime(5);


  Service[] services = {s1, s2, s3, s4, s5,s6};


 //Menu
  System.out.println("Choose your sort");
  System.out.println("1: Service");
  System.out.println("2: Price");
  System.out.println("3: Time");
  System.out.println("0: Exit");


   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

do{  
  x = Integer.parseInt(input.next());  



  switch(x)
  {
     case 1:
        sortByService(services);

        break;
     case 2:
        sortByPrice(services);
        break;
     case 3:
        sortByTime(services);
        break;
     case 0:
         break;
     default:
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
  }while(x!=0); 











          }

           }

      public static void sortByTime(Service[] array)
       {
          Service temp;
          int highSubscript = array.length - 1;
          for(int a = 0; a < highSubscript; ++a)
          {
              for(int b = 0; b < highSubscript; ++b)
              {
                if(array[b].getTime() > array[b+1].getTime())
                   {
                      temp = array[b];
                      array[b] = array[b + 1];
                      array[b + 1] = temp;
                   }
             }
          }

          for(int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
          {

             System.out.println("Service: "+array[i].getService()+", "+"Price: "            +array[i].getPrice()+", "+"Time: "+ array[i].getTime()); 
      }

   }

   public static void sortByService(Service[] array)
   {
      Service temp;
      int highSubscript = array.length - 1;
      for(int a = 0; a < highSubscript; ++a)
      {
         for(int b = 0; b < highSubscript; ++b)
         {
            if((array[b].getService().compareToIgnoreCase(array[b+1].getService())) >=     0)
               {
                  temp = array[b];
                  array[b] = array[b + 1];
                  array[b + 1] = temp;
               }
         }
      }

      for(int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
      {

         System.out.println("Service: "+array[i].getService()+", "+"Price: "     +array[i].getPrice()+", "+"Time: "+ array[i].getTime());        
      }

   }

   public static void sortByPrice(Service[] array)
   {
    Service temp;
      int highSubscript = array.length - 1;
      for(int a = 0; a < highSubscript; ++a)
      {
         for(int b = 0; b < highSubscript; ++b)
         {
            if(array[b].getPrice() > array[b+1].getPrice())
               {
                  temp = array[b];
                  array[b] = array[b + 1];
                  array[b + 1] = temp;
               }
         }
      }

      for(int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
      {
         System.out.println("Service: "+array[i].getService()+", "+"Price:  "+array[i].getPrice()+", "+"Time: "+ array[i].getTime());        
      }

   }


}


SalonReport.java:87: error: while expected
      }
       ^
SalonReport.java:91: error: illegal start of expression
  public static void sortByTime(Service[] array)
  ^
SalonReport.java:91: error: ')' expected
  public static void sortByTime(Service[] array)
        ^
SalonReport.java:91: error: ';' expected
  public static void sortByTime(Service[] array)
           ^
SalonReport.java:91: error: '.class' expected
  public static void sortByTime(Service[] array)
                                      ^
SalonReport.java:91: error: ';' expected
  public static void sortByTime(Service[] array)
                                           ^
SalonReport.java:116: error: illegal start of expression
   public static void sortByService(Service[] array)
   ^
SalonReport.java:116: error: illegal start of expression
   public static void sortByService(Service[] array)
          ^
SalonReport.java:116: error: ';' expected
   public static void sortByService(Service[] array)
            ^
SalonReport.java:116: error: '.class' expected
   public static void sortByService(Service[] array)
                                          ^
SalonReport.java:116: error: ';' expected
   public static void sortByService(Service[] array)
                                               ^
SalonReport.java:141: error: illegal start of expression
   public static void sortByPrice(Service[] array)
  ^
SalonReport.java:141: error: illegal start of expression
   public static void sortByPrice(Service[] array)
          ^
SalonReport.java:141: error: ';' expected
   public static void sortByPrice(Service[] array)
            ^
SalonReport.java:141: error: '.class' expected
   public static void sortByPrice(Service[] array)
                                        ^
SalonReport.java:141: error: ';' expected
   public static void sortByPrice(Service[] array)
                                             ^
SalonReport.java:166: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
17 errors

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a `}`

It should be

```
do{  
  x = Integer.parseInt(input.next());  
  switch(x)
  {
     case 1:
        sortByService(services);

        break;
     case 2:
        sortByPrice(services);
        break;
     case 3:
        sortByTime(services);
        break;
     case 0:
         break;
     default:
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
  }
}while(x!=0);
```

Comment: i think u mean } and not {

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `}` for switch case.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

do{
      x = Integer.parseInt(input.next());

```
  switch(x)
  {
     case 1:
        sortByService(services);

        break;
     case 2:
        sortByPrice(services);
        break;
     case 3:
        sortByTime(services);
        break;
     case 0:
         break;
     default:
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
  }











          }while(x!=0);
```